# How to create a grayscale bitmap with MFC?

Tags: windows, image, visual-studio, bitmap, mfc

I use Attach() to create a CBitmap from a .PNG image.

I noticed a degradation in quality and it appears that, while the dimensions are identical, the PNG image is transparent and grayscale, while the bitmap is monochrome.

How should I go about creating the bitmap as grayscale too (or even color) ?

```
CBitmap cbm;
CImage pngImage;

pngImage.Load(_T(".\\res\\ImageLab\\A.png"));
cbm.Attach(pngImage.Detach());  

return (HBITMAP)(cbm);
```

Comment: Show your code. We cannot tell what's wrong in your code if we cannot see it.

Comment: Added the code, thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to render the bitmap as gray-scale?

Comment: A [CBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t1yfd35.aspx) wraps a GDI bitmap. GDI bitmaps do not support alpha transparency, unlike PNG's.

Comment: Did you thing to use a bitmap extended class ? Something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1300/CxImage or http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29121/CBitmapEx-Free-C-Bitmap-Manipulation-Class ...

Comment: @flaviu2 : Very helpful recommendation, thank you. Currently looking into it.

Comment: Consider imgsource 6. It is free from smalleranimals.com. It is a rich image library.